# is there a way to use angular filters in ng-include?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-include

this is what I am trying to do:

```
ng-include=" 'views/directives/list_elements/'+ list.type.object | listobjects +'.html' "
```

without the filter it works fine

Comment: this is more of a javascript function situation i think.  basically just use the same filter function on the list.type.object in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters work inside of an expression, whereas `ng-include` assignment is a string. That's why, you can `ng-init` the value you want to be a part of the URL in the specific controller scope and then use it.

From [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

```
<script>
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.list = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']];
}
</script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="innerList in list" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
  <div ng-repeat="value in innerList" ng-init="innerIndex = $index">
     <span class="example-init">list[ {{outerIndex}} ][ {{innerIndex}} ] = {{value}};</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

For your case, you could do something like:

```
ng-init="url_part=list.type.object | listobjects +'.html'"
```

and then use it in your URL.

```
'views/directives/list_elements/'+url_part
```

Otherwise, you can also use this same filter within the controller.